docker.raw size > 350GB?
why do i have a Docker.raw file with more then 350GB size laying around in
/home/username/.docker/desktop/vms/0/data?
ls -lha Docker.raw 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 344G Dez  4 12:31 Docker.raw


i have tried docker system prune without any success of making it at least a little bit smaller.
i have some docker containers running, but docker system df does not show sizes even close to that raw file:
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          7         4         4.459GB   2.423GB (54%)
Containers      5         5         12.36GB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   33        3         6.321GB   6.117GB (96%)
Build Cache     47        20        37.51MB   0B


so what is it and how can i get rid of it (my disk space slowly runs out ;) )
Thanks a lot!
PS.: i am on debian linux

Are you on a mac by any chance? If so, take a look in your docker-desktop settings. I think that contains the virtual-machine that runs your containers. Although it seems very large even for that.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391377/what-is-the-purpose-of-docker-raw-file-on-mac-os-catalina I found this on stackexchange. you can try seeing what the output of du -sh Docker.raw is, since that reflects the size it takes up on the disk.

The /home/username path suggests a Linux host system with Docker Desktop.  The Desktop application isn't necessary there, and the file you're looking at is the storage for a Linux virtual machine.  It's possible that uninstalling Desktop, installing the open-source Docker engine, and deleting the $HOME/.desktop directory will have better disk utilization.

hi, i am on a linux system. and i really would like to keep docker desktop.

Does this github issue help?

yes it does! Thanks for the reply! It was set to use 1TB. why? idk.

Here is some additional information in the official docker docs.
